# How many Nella numbers $n$ are there with $50\le n\le 2017$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I don't where it is from therefore if it is against the rules sorry for posting it. I tried using primes however I am stuck. I would appreciate any help.

A positive integer $n$ with $n\ge3$ is called a Nella number if there exists a positive integer $x$ with $x<n$ and there exists a positive integer $m$ such that

- $m$ is not divisible by $x$ or by $x+1$, and
- $m$ is divisible by every other positive integer between $1$ and n inclusive.

For example, $n=7$ is a Nella number.

How many Nella numbers $n$ are there with $50\le n\le 2017$?

Comment: Are you sure that the first condition is not "$m$ is divisible by $x$ or $x+1$"? Because as written, both conditions together just say "$m$ is not divisible by every positive integer between 1 and $n$ inclusive", which is in itself a bit strange when you consider the lower bound 1 as included, but I assume that only the upper bound $n$ is considered included. But even in this case, every number is a Nella Number, by choosing $m=n!+1$.

Comment: Give more examples why some number $n$ is Nella number and why some other number $n$ is not Nella number

Comment: @Ingix Sorry about that just corrected the second part as divisible.

Comment: Now here's a sequence which has a name, but is _not on the OEIS_. That's not something you see every day. So I'd be very pleased to know where the name comes from.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $x$ should not divide $lcm(1,2,\ldots,x-1)$. This means that $x$ must be a prime power. The same is true of $x+1$. 
Once they are both prime powers, any value of $n$ from $x+1$ to $2x-1$ works.

Thus $(x,x+1)$ must be of the form $(2^r,2^r+1)$ with $2^r+1$ a prime power or $(2^r-1,2^r)$ with$2^r-1$ a prime power.

A method to find Nella numbers is therefore to first find all such $r,x$ as above, then to mark all $n \in [x+1,2x-1]$ as a Nella number.

Comment: The argument that $x$ and $x+1$ must be prime powers is lacking. Even prime powers are the "product of numbers less than it". A better argument would be that they cannot be the product of smaller, co-prime numbers, because $m$ would have to be divisible by those factors (second condition) and hence (because of co-primeness) be divisible by their product.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the phrasing.

Comment: I could only find 2 prime number that fits: 127, 257. However the answer is around 395. What am I missing?

Comment: With $x=127$ you get that numbers in $[128,254]$ are Nella, i.e. 126 numbers, similarly $[256,511]$ which gives 256 numbers. Together these give 382 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot $x=31$, that makes $n$ from $50$ to $61$.